# httpd.conf не сохраняется

Tags: apache, openserver

httpd.conf не сохраняется что делать?

Comment: Какие изменения вносите?

Comment: @Tarasovych добавляю `<IfModule alias_module>
Alias   /i/    "c:/openserver/domains/multisite/application/themes/mazilla.kz/img"
</IfModule>`

Comment: Можно выставить атрибут "только для чтения" в свойствах файла.

Comment: @Tarasovych пробовал

Comment: @Tarasovych погодите, только для чтения ? не для записи ?

Comment: Именно для чтения

Comment: @Tarasovych теперь openserver не хочет запускаться, говорит нет доступа к httpd.conf

Comment: При попытке внести изменения в файл ошибка есть какая-либо?

Comment: @Tarasovych нет